# I need a mathematical formula for my C++ client server project

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, client, formula

thanks in advance for your help․ I need a mathematical formula for my C++ client server project.

The client part has a function startDataGeneration(**N, n, k**) where **N** is the total amount of data that the server should generate or read from the file, **n** is the amount of data that each iteration wants to be sent from the server to the client, and **k** is the amount of data amount to be discarded on the server and not sent to the client.
I need a formula to calculate how much data will come from the server in order to reserve so much memory in the client.

- case1:

  - N = 11, n = 3, k = 0.
  - Result: 11 pieces of data will be sent to the client, which will happen as a result of 4 iterations: 3 pieces of data will be sent in 3 iterations, and 2 pieces of data in the last iteration.
- case2:

  - N = 11, n = 3, k = 3․
  - Result: 6 pieces of data will be sent to the client, which will happen as a result of 2 iterations: 3 pieces of data will be sent, and 3 pieces of data will be skiped to the first iteration and 2 pieces of data to the second.

This formula didn't work․ `n * ceil((N / (n + k)))`

Comment: `N / (n + k)` looks like integer division what with use of `ceil` looks suspicious. Read how division works for integer types.

Comment: Yes I know, I created double versions of the numbers then tried that formula

Comment: BTW prefer actual code over text description. Code is unambiguous and can be tested. Also when asking question why something do not work provide examples with input data, expected result vs actual result.

Comment: If you know how division with integrals work, why you've wrote this expression with `ceil` which do nothing here?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qKb5z3xc4

Comment: Thank you for the advice Mark:). I decided to just write a function that would calculate it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You find the number of iterations with **ceil((N / (n + k)))** and multiply it with **n** to find the total number of data to be sent. However, this fails because sometimes at the last iteration you actually send less than **n** pieces of data.

Here is how you can account for this situation:

1. Find number of iterations, as you already do. Let's call it A.

   **A = ceil((N / (n + k)))**
2. Find leftover data after **A-1** iterations. Let's call it B.

   **B = N mod (n + k)**
3. Find how many pieces of data will be sent at the last iteration. Let's call it C.

   **if (B < n) then C = B; else C = n**
4. Finally, find the total data to be sent.

   **Total = (A-1) * n + C**

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just write a function that would calculate it in a loop

```cpp
size_t TaskManager::countIncomingSamplesNumber(uint64_t N, uint64_t n, uint64_t k)
{
    size_t Count = 0;

    while (N >= n + k)
    {
        N -= (n + k);
        Count += n;
    }

    Count += std::min(N, n);

    return Count;
}
```